# how to draw many CCSprite without slow performance?

Tags: performance, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm making such a arrow shooting game. Everything is good. but I realized if I draw line  tracking my arrow, It will be great. so I put some code on my game in my Scheduler that is supposed to draw circle where arrow is going. But I had to draw so many circle, so game frame is not good when I shoot multi arrow.

Is there other better way? I use CCSpriteBatchNode, plist, CCSpriteFrameCache already. I did all I can do. I need help Thanks so much

this is my code

```
...............
    [self schedule:@selector(CollisionDetection:)];
}


- (void)CollisionDetection:(ccTime)dt 
{
    for (CCSprite *arrow in arrows->arrowsArray) 
    {
            CCSprite *track = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"WhiteCircle.png"];
            [track setPosition:arrow.position];
            [arrows->rootLayer->arrowsSheet addChild:track];

            id delete = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.0];
            id deleteAction= [CCSequence actions:delete ,[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteActionFinished:)], nil];
            [track runAction:deleteAction];
    .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allocation of objects is a large overhead. If your game runs to slow you should consider creating a pool of arrows at the beginning of the game and only trigger the action on it as soon as you need it. If it is not visible anymore just set it to inactive and reuse it the next time you need an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem isn't the arrows, but the circles, which I imagine are Cocos objects too. You'd be better off learning how to draw the circle texture directly to the screen using opengl commands instead of objects. That'll help a lot.

Comment: really? you think it's gonna work? I thought same thing. but I was wondering How that's getting better if I draw using opengl API. you think it's big difference between CCSprite and opengl?

Comment: There's a lot less overhead. No objects are being created per circle, you're just drawing X texture at Y coordinates. And remember, a CCSprite eventually calls opengl to draw itself anyway. You're just cutting out the heavy-set middleman. Plus, going back over your code, you are creating your circles every frame. That's bad.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't give up CCSprite's incredible function! like a FadeOut, but Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When have a time critical animation, i stay clear from CCCallFunc(N), as it can stall the scheduler for a noticeable amount of time. As I read your code, you have a CallFunc at every scheduled interval ... hmmmm. Have you tried running this without the scheduler, ie package and start all your animations at once, with a single CallFunc at the end ? Instead of changing the position as part of the scheduled interval, use a CCMoveTo that you will run at the same time as your tracking animation.

Comment: hm that makes sense :) Thanks I will fix it.

Comment: my pleasure. If it works for you, you know how to accept the answer :) Best of luck with your product.